# How to plot(ly) a subset of a uploaded dataset using shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a xls file from [here](http://www.saedsayad.com/datasets/Iris.xls). First, how can i reduce complexity of my code on server-side? How to get data at once? (guess reactive but how?) Second, the user will choose from the category but how to use * subset * data in plot_ly()? My code is below. Can someone help me to check? Thanks.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(plotly)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("File Input Test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("Xfile", "Choose xls file:",
                accept = c(".xls")
      ),

      uiOutput("here")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server = function(input, output){

  output$here <- renderUI({

    UserFile <- input$Xfile

    if(is.null(UserFile))
      return(NULL)
    file.rename(UserFile$datapath, paste(UserFile$datapath, ".xls", sep=""))
    test <- read_excel(paste(UserFile$datapath, ".xls", sep=""), 1)

    selectInput(inputId = "xyz", label = "Choose one:", choices = unique(test[[5]]))

  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

    UserFile <- input$Xfile

    if(is.null(UserFile))
      return(NULL)
    file.rename(UserFile$datapath, paste(UserFile$datapath, ".xls", sep=""))
    test <- read_excel(paste(UserFile$datapath, ".xls", sep=""), 1)

    plot_ly(subset(Iris, Iris[[5]] %in% input$xyz), x=~test[[1]], y=~test[[2]])

  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I guess the "Iris" in the plot_ly line should be test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first question. Indeed reactive does the trick

```
  dat<-reactive({
    UserFile <- input$Xfile

    if(is.null(UserFile))
      return(NULL)
    file.rename(UserFile$datapath, paste(UserFile$datapath, ".xls", sep=""))
    test <- read_excel(paste(UserFile$datapath, ".xls", sep=""), 1)
  })

  output$here <- renderUI({
    test <- dat()
    if(is.null(test))
      return(NULL)
    selectInput(inputId = "xyz", label = "Choose one:", choices = unique(test[[5]]))

  })
```

The plot can be done similarly.

(On subset data you would have to elaborate what you mean.)

The following code might fix your subset problem
      output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        test <- dat()
        if(is.null(test))
          return(NULL)

```
    sset<- subset(test, test[[5]] %in% input$xyz)
    plot_ly(sset, x=~sset[[1]], y=~sset[[2]])

  })
```